# Pandas Resampling Hourly OHLC to Daily OHLC

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe of hourly OHLC as follows (please ignore the values of OHLC, I typed them in for better illustration),

```
hr_df =
                        Close      High       Low      Open
2017-09-04 05:00:00  0.715035  0.715035  0.715035  0.715035
2017-09-04 06:00:00  0.715035  0.715045  0.715015  0.715035
2017-09-04 07:00:00  0.715040  0.715050  0.714035  0.715035
:
:
2017-09-05 05:00:00  0.715045  0.715105  0.714985  0.715035
2017-09-05 06:00:00  0.715040  0.716045  0.714605  0.715035
2017-09-05 07:00:00  0.715040  0.717045  0.713225  0.715035
:
:
2017-09-06 05:00:00  0.715040  0.714045  0.713355  0.715035
```

I want to resample it into daily OHLC, example,

```
day_df =
               Close      High       Low      Open
2017-09-04  0.715035  0.715035  0.715035  0.715035
2017-09-05  0.715035  0.715045  0.715015  0.715035
2017-09-06  0.715040  0.715050  0.714035  0.715035
2017-09-07  0.715045  0.715105  0.714985  0.715035
2017-09-08  0.715040  0.716045  0.714605  0.715035
2017-09-09  0.715040  0.714045  0.713355  0.715035
2017-09-10  0.715040  0.717045  0.713225  0.715035
```

I tried using pandas resample method, `day_df = hr_df.resample('D').pad()` or `day_df = hr_df.resample('D').ohlc()` but it is not working. I know I am probably not using the proper method. I will really appreciate it if someone can guide me to an alternative solution or the proper method to use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need downsample by [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) by `dictionary` with keys for column names and values for functions:

```
day_df = (hr_df.resample('D')
               .agg({'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'}))
print (day_df)
                Open      High    Close       Low
2017-09-04  0.715035  0.715050  0.71504  0.714035
2017-09-05  0.715035  0.717045  0.71504  0.713225
2017-09-06  0.715035  0.714045  0.71504  0.713355
```

Comment: I tried doing the same as above, however the result I get is completely different, mine looks like a multiindexed df with open/high/low/close appearing in my index and only one column.
Would you have any idea of how to fix it and why it's not doing the same as you did?

Comment: @Erlinska - Not easy find problem, but I have one idea - is `DatetimeIndex` sorted? Maybe some data in another rows of DataFrame and you do no know about it.

Comment: The DataFrame is exactly like the one in the question, I'm not sure of what a sorted DataTimeIndex is, the one I'm using is just read from a csv using `pd.read_csv(filename,index_col='DateTime',parse_dates=True)`

Comment: @Erlinska did you ever solve this im dealing with it now

Comment: Quickest and most elegant way of resampling I have found so far!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `pd.Grouper`. If pair is a forex pair for example you can use it as index together with the newly grouped date:

```
hr_df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='D'), 'pair']).agg(
{'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last'})
```

Answer (score 1):

That works for me.

```
quotes.set_index('end', inplace=True)
quotes.index = pd.to_datetime(quotes.index)
ohlc_dict = {
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last'
}
quotes.resample("1D", closed='left', label='left').apply(ohlc_dict).dropna()
```